# Servlet Method not found exception

Tags: java, servlet-filters

Even if there is the method, I am getting method not found exception as servlet exception

My Bean's init and the method:

```
public void init() {
    HttpServletRequest req =
            (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    usrLinks = db.usrLinks(String.valueOf(req.getParameter("username")));
}


public List<UserLinks> getUsrLinks() {
    return usrLinks;
}
```

The xhtml tags that I get the error message from:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{userBean.usrLinks}" value="My Links" rendered="#{loginBean.loggedin}" />
```

the exception error:

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/template.xhtml @22,100 action="#{userBean.usrLinks}": Method not found: class bean.UserBean.usrLinks()

Comment: I solved the problem using this link's third answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320279/javax-el-methodnotfoundexception-method-not-found-jsf

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, there are two solutions:

Rename `getUsrLinks()` to `usrLinks()`

or change `#{userBean.usrLinks}` to `#{userBean.getUsrLinks}`